# How to close add-in pane in outlook Mail App read scenario through JavaScript Api (office.js)

Tags: outlook-addin, office-js, outlook-web-addins

I have developed a Mail App (Read Scenario) Add-in for Outlook365. After certain task performed I would like to see add-in pane collapse automatically. Is there any method defined yet in office.js API to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about Outlook Online(outlook as a web app), then I am afraid there's no method defined yet in Office.js to collapse the task pane yet. But I agree it is an important scenario and we will absolutely add it to our backlog.

Thanks,
Sky

Comment: Yes I can see this is in plan [here](http://appsforoutlook.uservoice.com/forums/284413-mail-read-apis/suggestions/7339685-close-app-api)

Comment: FWIW I also have a requirement for this - any timeframe for release? Thx

Comment: I am still waiting for any updates on it? @MarkyRoden please vote it up the question so that it can be visible to the community?